# How to unselect other AppBarToggleButton UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I m doing an UWP project, and I'm using the CommandBar.
In my command Bar I have multiple `AppBarToggleButton`, when I click to one of them I wan't that the other `AppBarToggleButton` are unselect.
Is there an options to do that ?

Here is a symple code :

```
<CommandBar>
<AppBarToggleButton Icon="Shuffle" Label="Shuffle" Click="AppBarButton_Click" />
<AppBarToggleButton Icon="RepeatAll" Label="Repeat" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>


<CommandBar.Content>
    <TextBlock Text="Now playing..." Margin="12,14"/>
</CommandBar.Content>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to `x:Name` your buttons and manually set `IsChecked` to `False` whenever the other one is clicked.

```
private void AppBarButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AppBarButton2.IsChecked = false;
}
```

---

### Update

A pure XAML solution would be using bindings. Note you will need an `InvertedBooleanConverter` here.

```
IsChecked="{x:Bind Toggle1.IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

---

### Bonus

I really dislike the binding approach so here's a pure XAML solution built with a behavior. Note you will need to first install the XAML Behaviors from the Nuget Package Manager -

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed -Version 2.0.0
```

This `AutoDeselectToggleButtonBehavior` behavior below basically gets all the `AppBarToggleButton`s once the `CommandBar` is loaded, subscribe to all their `Click` events and in the handlers, simply de-select all the other toggles except the clicked one.

```
public class AutoDeselectToggleButtonBehavior : Behavior<CommandBar>
{
    private IEnumerable<AppBarToggleButton> _toggleButtons;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;

        base.OnAttached();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        foreach (var toggle in _toggleButtons)
        {
            toggle.Click -= OnToggleClick;
        }

        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;

        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Children extension method:
        // https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/Continuity/blob/master/Continuity/Extensions/UtilExtensions.cs#L25
        _toggleButtons = AssociatedObject.Children().OfType<AppBarToggleButton>();

        foreach (var toggle in _toggleButtons)
        {
            toggle.Click += OnToggleClick;
        }
    }

    private void OnToggleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedToggle = (AppBarToggleButton)sender;

        foreach (var toggle in _toggleButtons)
        {
            if (toggle != clickedToggle)
            {
                toggle.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once it's in place, just attach it to your `CommandBar` like the following -

```
<CommandBar>
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:AutoDeselectToggleButtonBehavior />
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Clean and reusable. :)

Comment: Hi Justin, I did taht but It makes a lot of code behing there is no other way ?

Comment: I m not sure but if there is more than two appbarbutton the xaml method will work ?

Comment: The thing is these are toggle buttons not radio buttons so there's no easy way to do this. To be honest the best way I see is still the first approach, that's an actual click input, instead of relying on a bool property. Code-behind in this case clearly wins.

Comment: If you really fancy a no code-behind solution, I'd create a Behavior and attach it to the CommandBar and encapsulate all the logic there.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try it :)